# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\appserv\www\Cocolani\php\req\register.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, flash

I'm still a beginner programmer , so I hope you give the solution step by step.

I'm trying to make a private server for a flash game and i have a problem that I don't know how can I solve it at all .
I wanna connect the game with the database , and when someone tries to make an account (register) in the game , the account data supposed to be saved in the database ( like: username,password,mask color,birth date,register date,etc...) but it doesn't happen

The file which is responsible about this step is called " register.php" and
I keep getting this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\appserv\www\Cocolani\php\req\register.php on line 4
```

the problem is in this line :

```
$db = new database($obj->get("db_name"), $obj->get("db_server"), $obj->get("db_user"), $obj->get("db_password"), $obj->get("url_root"));
```

and this is "register.php"  :

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
include_once("settings.php");
$db = new database($obj->get("db_name"), $obj->get("db_server"), $obj->get("db_user"), $obj->get("db_password"), $obj->get("url_root"));

$FROM_EMAIL = $obj->getEmailFrom();

function generateTribeCurrency($ID, $db) {

//  $db = new database();

    // get init purse amount
    $db->setQuery("SELECT init_purse_amount FROM `cc_def_settings`");
    $row = $db->loadResult();
    $init_purse_amount = $row->init_purse_amount;

        // load tribe info
    $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_tribes`");
    $tribeinfo = $db->loadResults();

    $newstr = array();      
    foreach ($tribeinfo as $i) {
        if ($ID == $i->ID) array_push($newstr, $init_purse_amount); else array_push($newstr, 0);
    }
    $newstr = implode(",", $newstr);

    return $newstr;
}

$hackchk = false;

 foreach($_POST as $POST) {
$POST = mysqli_real_escape_string($POST);
}

function remove_bad_symbols($s) {
return preg_replace(
  array(0=>'#/#', 1=>'#\\\#', 2=>'#;#', 3=>'#{#', 4=>'#}#', 5=>'#<#', 6=>'#>#', 7=>'#@#', 8=>'#\'#', 9=>'# #', 10=>'#"#') // patterns
  , '' // replacements
  , $s);
 }

 $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? remove_bad_symbols($_POST['username']) : "";
 $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "";
 $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
 $birthdate = isset($_POST['birthdate']) ? $_POST['birthdate'] : "";
 $firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : "";
 $lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : "";
 $sex = isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : "";
 $tribeid = isset($_POST['clan']) ? $_POST['clan'] : "";
 $mask = isset($_POST['mask']) ? $_POST['mask'] : "";
 $mask_color = isset($_POST['maskcl']) ? $_POST['maskcl'] : "";
 $lang_id = isset($_POST['lang_id']) ? $_POST['lang_id'] : 0;

 $error = '';

 $purse = generateTribeCurrency((int) $tribeid, $db);

 // get language suffix 
 if ($lang_id != 0) {
 $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_extra_langs` WHERE id='{$lang_id}'");
 $res = $db->loadResult();
 $lang = "_".$res->lang;
 } else $lang = "";  


 $db->setQuery("SELECT one_email_per_registration FROM `cc_def_settings`");
 $res = $db->loadResult();
 $one_registration_per_email = ($res->one_email_per_registration == 1);

 $email_check_ok = true;
 if ($one_registration_per_email == true) {
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM `cc_user` WHERE email='{$email}'"; 
 // for several registrations per one email address -- no check  
   $db->setQuery($sql);
   $res1 = $db->loadResult();
   $email_check_ok = $res1->counter == "0";
 }

 // first check there is no username with this name already registered.
 $db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM `cc_user` WHERE username='".$username."'");
 $res = $db->loadResult();

 if ($username && $email && $sex && $birthdate) {
     if ($email_check_ok) {
   if ($res->counter == "0") {
        // check that there are no registrations from this same IP in the last 2 hours
        $db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as counter FROM `cc_userreginfo` WHERE IP='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)<register_date)");
        $regcheck = $db->loadResult(); 
        if (($regcheck != null && (int)($regcheck->counter) == 0) || $hackchk == false) {

      // get number of already registered number of registrations with this email address                    
      $query = $db->setQuery("SELECT count(*) as registered_num_emails FROM `cc_user` WHERE email='{$email}'");
      $row = $db->loadResult();
      $already_registered_num_emails = $row->registered_num_emails;

      // get max number of accounts per email from settings table
      $query = $db->setQuery("SELECT max_num_account_per_email from `cc_def_settings`");
      $row = $db->loadResult();
      $max_num_account_per_email = $row->max_num_account_per_email;

      if ($already_registered_num_emails < $max_num_account_per_email) {

              $uniqid = uniqid(); 
                $newreq = "INSERT INTO `cc_user` (`ID`,`username`, `password`, `email`, `birth_date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `sex`, `about`, `mask`, `mask_colors`, `clothing`, `tribe_ID` , `money`, `happyness`, `rank_ID`, `status_ID`, `lang_id`, `register_date`, uniqid, permission_id) VALUES ";
                $newreq .= "(NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}', '{$birthdate}', '{$firstname}' , '{$lastname}', '{$sex}', '', '{$mask}', '{$mask_color}', '', '{$tribeid}', '{$purse}', 50, 0, 3, '{$lang_id}', NOW(), '{$uniqid}', 4)";
                $db->setQuery($newreq);
                $res = $db->runQuery();
                if ($res) {
                  // add registration info into the userreginfo table as well.
                    $iid = $db->mysqlInsertID();
                    $db->setQuery("INSERT INTO `cc_userreginfo` (`ID`, `user_id`, `register_IP`, `register_date`, `last_update`) VALUES (NULL, ".$iid.",'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', NOW(), NOW())");
                    $res2 = $db->runQuery();

                    $counter = ($regcheck != null) ? $regcheck->counter : 0; 
                    echo 'response=true&reg='.$counter;
            // ----------------------------------
            // send confirmation email
            // ----------------------------------                        
            $cur_lang = ($lang != "") ? substr($lang, 1)."/" : "";            
            $msg = $obj->getTranslation(-13, $lang, "email_templates", "id", "content");
            $msg = str_replace("%FIRST_NAME%", $firstname, $msg);  
            $msg = str_replace("%LAST_NAME%", $lastname, $msg);
            $msg = str_replace("&#039;", "'", $msg);              
            $msg = str_replace("%CONFIRM%", '<a href="'.$obj->get("url_root").'/'.$cur_lang.'registration-confirmed?confirmregistration='.$uniqid.'">confirm</a>', $msg);
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: '.$FROM_EMAIL."\r\n";
            //mail($email, $obj->getTranslation(-13, $lang, "email_templates", "id", "subject"), $msg, $headers);

            include "../../admin/php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php";
            $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
            $body = $msg;
            $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
            $mail->SetFrom($FROM_EMAIL);
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->Subject = $obj->getTranslation(-13, $lang, "email_templates", "id", "subject");
            $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
              die("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
            } else {
              //echo "Message sent!";
            }            
            // ----------------------------------
                } else {
                    echo 'response=false';
                }

      } else {
        // get warning message from db
        $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='MAX_NUM_REGISTRATION_REACHED'");
        $res = $db->loadResult();
              echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
      }  


        } else {
      // get warning message from db
      $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='REGISTER_LATER'");
        $res = $db->loadResult();
          echo 'errorhide='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
        }
     } else {
     // get warning message from db
     $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='USERNAME_IN_USE'");
     $res = $db->loadResult();
       echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
     }
 } else {
   //if ($one_registration_per_email == true) 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='DUPLICATED_EMAIL'"; //else $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='DUPLICATED_REGISTRATION'";
   // get warning message from db
   $db->setQuery($sql);
     $res = $db->loadResult();
       echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
   }
 } else {
 // get warning message from db
 $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='REGFORM_PROBLEM'");
 $res = $db->loadResult();     
     echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
 }   

 ?>
```

note : "register.php" requires two files so maybe the error is in one of them

settings.php :

```
<?php

$db_server = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "qazqazqaz1";
$db_name = "coco"; 

$connect = mysqli_connect("$db_server","$db_user","$db_password","$db_name");


?>
```

db.php:

```
<?php

class database {
var $_debug = 0;
var $_sql = '';
var $_error = '';
var $_prefix = '';

var $_numrows = 0;

var $_DBhost = 'localhost';
var $_DBuser = "root";
var $_DBpass = "qazqazqaz1";
var $_DBname = "cocol";
var $url_root = "localhost/cocolani";

public function __construct($dbname = 'cocolani_battle', $dbuser = 'root', $dbpsw = 'pass1234', $dbhost = 'localhost', $urlroot = 'localhost/cocolani') {

        $this->_DBname = 'cocolani_battle';
        $this->_DBuser = 'root';
        $this->_DBpass = 'pass1234';
        $this->url_root = 'localhost/cocolani';
        $this->_DBhost = 'localhost';

    $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this->_DBhost, $this->_DBuser, $this->_DBpass) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
    mysqli_select_db($this->_connection, $this->_DBname) or die("Select DB Error: ".mysqli_error());

}

public function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->_connection);
}

function debug($debug_level) {
    $this->_debug = intval($debug_level);   
}

function setQuery($sql) {
    /* queries are given in the form of #__table need to replace that with the prefix */
    $this->_sql = str_replace('#__', $this->_prefix.'_', $sql);
}

function getQuery() {
    return "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars( $this->_sql) . "</pre>";
}

function prepareStatement($sql) {
    $this->sql = mysqli_prepare($this->_connection, $sql);
    return $this->sql;
}

function runQuery($num_rows=0) {
    mysqli_select_db($this->_connection, $this->_DBname) or die("Select DB Error: ".mysqli_error());

    $this->_numrows = 0;
    $result = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $this->_sql);
    if ($this->_debug > 1) echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars( $this->_sql) . "</pre>";

    if (!$result) {
        $this->_error = mysqli_error($this->_connection);
        if ($this->_debug) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $this->getQuery() . $this->_error;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if ($num_rows) {
        $this->_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
    return $result;
}

/* Retrieve Mysql insert id */
function mysqlInsertID() {
    $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id();
    return $insert_id;
}

/* Escapes special characters while inserting to db */
function db_input($string) {
  if (is_array($string)) {
      $retArray = array();
      foreach($string as $key => $value) {
          $value = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : $value);
          $retArray[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
      }
      return $retArray;
  } else {
      $string = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($string) : $string);
      return mysqli_real_escape_string($string);

  }
}


function getError() {
    return $this->_error;
}
/* Load results into csv formatted string */
function loadCsv() {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        return null;
    }

    $csv_string = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value ) {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ) {
                $value = ",";
            } else { 
                $value = $value. ",";
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $line = substr($line, 0, -1);
        $csv_string .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $csv_string = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $csv_string );
        //$csv_string .= implode(",", $row) . "\n";
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $csv_string;
}

/* Load multiple results */
function loadResults($key='' ) {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        return null;
    }
    $array = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
        if ($key) {
            $array[strtolower($row->$key)] = $row;
        } else {
            $array[] = $row;
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $array;
}

function loadResult() {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        if ($this->_debug) echo 'Error: ' . $this->_error;
        return null;
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $row;
}

/* Load a result field into an array */
function loadArray() {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        return null;
    }
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        $array[] = $row[0];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $array;
}

/* Load a row into an associative an array */
function loadAssoc() {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        return null;
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $row;
}

/* Return one field */
function loadField() {
    if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
        return null;
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        $field = $row[0];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $field;
}

?>
```

I tried to solve it myself but I lost hope , so please tell me the accurate solution in steps .

thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your database has `null` values in it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge you mean there is no values?
if u mean that yeah because the game is programmed to full the values
when tha player choose the username password mask etc... they supposed to be saved in the database by register.php

Comment: `$obj` comes from were? its not in your code

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a beginner programmer as i said so I'm not sure from where but i think from db.php ? @tim

Comment: nope, no `$obj=`  in there

Comment: I'm not the one who programmed this game, this flash game has been closed 2 years ago and I'm trying make a private server for the game on localhost. @tim

Comment: the method get() is not in there either, your missing some things, thats all i can say

Comment: @tim Oh is this the only problem? I mean when I solve it It will work without any other problems?

Comment: even if I spent hours reading that code, I can't say if it would work without trying it. Being new, this is really not a good place to start.

Comment: @tim thank you very much and sorry for disturbing you 
I don't think there's another problem with the codecs because I'm not the one who programmed these files but the ones who made the game
Can you tell me at least how to start solving the problem?
 for example, how can i make $obj ?

Comment: You are connecting TWICE. This code connects `include_once("db.php");`  and then you try and do it again using `include_once("settings.php");`. Being a beginner is great, but you do have to look at the code you have collected and try and understand it

Answer (score -2):

The error is referring to `$obj->get`. Basically you're executing the `get` method on a null variable, meaning it doesn't exist. After looking through all the code you have there, you aren't declaring `$obj` at any point.

I think you might need to check how you're passing in your settings to your Database object. For example:

```
$db = new database($db_server, ... , ...);
```

Updated:
You're hardcoding your connection anyway, just don't pass anything to the DB object.

Change this:

```
$db = new database($obj->get("db_name"), $obj->get("db_server"), $obj->get("db_user"), $obj->get("db_password"), $obj->get("url_root"));
```

To this:

```
$db = new database();
```

Comment: At first I thank you very much for your help
but the problem as i said I'm a beginner programmer so can you explain more shall i do?

Comment: oh okay so I just need to change the line as you said .

Comment: Thank you, the problem disappeared, but the registration doesn't work even though the file does not show any problem , so I think that if i write $obj it will be better
I mean to write the $obj in another file, for example @Zitzabis